# How to Delete Rows in Excel Worksheet based on a Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook, in worksheet1 in Column A, IF the value of that column = ERR I want it to be deleted (the entire row), how is that possible?

PS: keep in mind that I have never used VBA or Macros before, so detailed description is much appreciated.

Comment: Maen, I'm curious did you read my answer, was there something you don't understand about it?

Comment: I agree with reafidy, his code was more compact. Perhaps you missed his multi sheet update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an autofilter either manually or with VBA (as below) is a very efficient way to remove rows

The code below

1. Works on the entire usedrange, ie will handle blanks
2. Can be readily adpated to other sheets by changing  `strSheets = Array(1, 4)`. ie this code currently runs on the first and fourth sheets

   ```
    Option Explicit


   Sub KillErr()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim lRow As Long
   Dim lngCol As Long
   Dim rng1 As Range
   Dim strSheets()
   Dim strws As Variant
   strSheets = Array(1, 4)
   For Each strws In strSheets
       Set ws = Sheets(strws)
       lRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
       lngCol = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       ws.Rows(1).Insert
       Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, lngCol), ws.Cells(lRow + 1, lngCol))
       With rng1.Offset(0, 1)
           .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC1=""ERR"""
           .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="TRUE"
           .EntireRow.Delete
           On Error Resume Next
           .EntireColumn.Delete
           On Error GoTo 0
       End With
   Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: thx niko :) although in this case I like Reafidy's more direct version as my working column in unnecessary in this case where a condition doesn't need to be added. A combo of Reafidy's code with my sheet array appraoch is probably the best overall solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I inserted it and it worked for the First Worksheet and only when ERR is in the first column, and I still got error: Run-time Error "91" Object variable or with block variable not set. so how do I make it work for other worksheets and other columns?

Comment: Error at:  lRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

Comment: I guess your code must have made more sense! ;)  Oh well, ya win some ya lose some! All good.

Comment: :) yes, I've had several solutions that I considered more efficient/robust/flexible overlooked. I think this is the first one at SO where the situation has been reversed

Comment: Yes, I have seen a couple of yours sadly overlooked, I usually add a comment, like you did above for me. Not so much in this thread but as you probably know its very common for users to develop mind sets, they see something that resembles what they thought they wanted.   "You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink"

Comment: I got that, how about making it work on columns other than the first column? or on more than one column?

Answer (score 2):

```
  sub delete_err_rows()
      Dim Wbk as Excel.workbook  'create excel workbook object
      Dim Wsh as worksheet       ' create excel worksheet object 
      Dim Last_row as long
      Dim i as long
      Set Wbk = Thisworkbook ' im using thisworkbook, assuming current workbook
                             ' if you want any other workbook just give the name 
                             ' in invited comma as "workbook_name"
      Set Wsh ="sheetname"   ' give the sheet name here 
      Wbk.Wsh.activate
     ' it means Thisworkbook.sheets("sheetname").activate
     ' here the sheetname of thisworkbook is activated
     ' or if you want looping between sheets use thisworkbook.sheets(i).activate
     ' put it in loop , to loop through the worksheets
     ' use thisworkbook.worksheets.count to find number of sheets in workbook
     Last_row = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'to find the lastrow of the activated sheet
          For i = lastrow To 1 step -1
             if activesheet.cells(i,"A").value = "yourDesiredvalue"
                  activesheet.cells(i,"A").select  ' select the row
                  selection.entirerow.delete       ' now delete the entire row
             end if
          Next i
   end sub
```

Note any operations that you do using activesheet , will be affected on the currently activated sheet

As your saying your a begginner, why dont you record a macro and check out, Thats the greatest way to automate your process by seeing the background code

Just find the macros tab on the sheet and click record new macro , then select any one of the row and do what you wanted to do , say deleting the entire row, just delete the entire row and now go back to macros tab and click stop recording .

Now click alt+F11 , this would take you to the VBA editor there you find some worksheets and modules in the vba project explorer field , if you dont find it search it using the view tab of the VBA editor, Now click on module1 and see the recorded macro , you will find something like these

```
        selection.entirerow.delete
```

I hope i helped you a bit , and if you need any more help please let me know, Thanks

Comment: Niko, you cannot delete rows like that.  The code you posted will give very bad results.  You must instead work backwards.  `For i = Last_row To 1 Step -1`

Comment: @Reafidy absolutely I just forgot I appreciate for finding out the bug in my code! great help Thanks !

Comment: Whoops forgot to actually add the +1!

Answer (score 2):

Fastest method:

```
Sub DeleteUsingAutoFilter()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        .Columns("A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="ERR"

        .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete        

        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Second fastest method (lots of variations to this one too):

```
Sub DeleteWithFind()
    Dim rFound As Range, rDelete As Range
    Dim sAddress As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Columns("A")
        Set rFound = .Find(What:="ERR", After:=.Resize(1, 1), SearchOrder:=xlByRows)

        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            Set rDelete = rFound                
            Do
                Set rDelete = Union(rDelete, rFound)
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
            Loop While rFound.Row > rDelete.Row                
        End If

        If Not rDelete Is Nothing Then rDelete.EntireRow.Delete

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Autofilter method for multiple sheets:

```
Sub DeleteUsingAutoFilter()
    Dim vSheets As Variant
    Dim wsLoop As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '// Define worksheet names here
    vSheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")

    For Each wsLoop In Sheets(vSheets)

         With wsLoop
             .AutoFilterMode = False

             .Columns("A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="ERR"

             .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete

             .AutoFilterMode = False
         End With

    Next wsLoop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: @Refidy +1 great job! never seen a code like these to delete a row !

Comment: +1 Nice and direct with the autofilter. From Maen's comment at bottom a small tweak to handle multiple sheets might be useful.

Comment: @brett & niko, thank you! - I have updated for multiple sheets as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are always values in the cells in column A and that the data is in the first sheet, then something like this should do what you want:

```
Sub deleteErrRows()
    Dim rowIdx As Integer
    rowIdx = 1

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    While ws.Cells(rowIdx, 1).Value <> ""
        If ws.Cells(rowIdx, 1).Value = "ERR" Then
            ws.Cells(rowIdx, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            rowIdx = rowIdx + 1
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will need this Macro for more than one sheet inside the same workbook so its not always the first sheet, and the column in question is not continuous (sometimes there are blanks), but in my condition I am looking for a specific text such as "ERROR"